# Are hunting questions on topic for the Great Outdoors?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions related to the sport of hunting (and fishing) on topic for The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange?

If you visit the **[Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors)**, you'll see that `Fishing and Hunting` has been merged into The Great Outdoors:

[image]

Does this mean that it is on topic?  Can I ask about how to track a deer in the forest?  Or how to fly fish in shallow streams?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, I would consider hunting on-topic, and I think the fact that, as you pointed out, fishing and *hunting* was merged into this site means that we should definitely consider it on-topic.